# iPhone 6 issue: Elements not visible

Tags: html, ios, ios8, iphone-6

I have a strange problem in iPhone 6. In iPhone 5 it works and also in Chrome development tools with device "iPhone 6" selected.

The page http://www.duperretmuenchen.de/ contains five elements with images, but in iPhone 6 only two elements (the first and the last) are shown.

That's the code of the five elements. But I doubt this will help:

```
<div class="ym-grid">
  <a id="c846"></a>
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above csc-textpic-1-columns">
    <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
      <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
        <a class="lightbox" href="/projekte/bauvorhaben-fuerstenfeldbruck/">
          <span class="expand" title="Bild vergrößern"></span>
          <img src="/uploads/pics/DU_M_1haus1_260x160.jpg" alt="DU M 1haus1 260x160" height="161" width="260">
        </a>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="csc-textpic-text">some text...</div>
  </div>
  <a id="c845"></a>
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above csc-textpic-1-columns">contents are nearly the same like above</div>
  <a id="c720"></a>
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above csc-textpic-1-columns">contents are nearly the same like above</div>
  <a id="c850"></a>
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above csc-textpic-1-columns">contents are nearly the same like above</div>
  <a id="c851"></a>
  <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above csc-textpic-1-columns">contents are nearly the same like above</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to give us some code or something to go on.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I thought you will have a look on the page. I've added some HTML code above.

Comment: I have no idea what technology you are even talking about.  Is it HTML?  How about some better tagging and some source code or something.  Most unclear.

Comment: Yes, that is HTML. HTML source code added shortly before your contribution. I've provided an example (www.duperretmuenchen.de) which  shows the problem.